# can I pass a js array into an input field

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

I'm trying to pass an array to an input field in a chat. The array passed is after meeting certain conditions. 
For example in this code below, the array comes from a loop over another div element.
So when the user selects an option, based on the selection, the array is passed as an answer.
This is my code below;

```
<select name="result" id="result" dataquestion="Click on the button below to know your answer.">
    <option value="my result">Yes</option>
    <option value="no result">No</option>
</select>
<div data-fork="result">
    <div data-case="my result" id="responses">
        <input type="text" data-answer="[]">
    </div>
    <div data-case="no result" id="response">
        <input name="thought" data-answer="[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target">i love a cat</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array1 = []
    //var array1 = ["i love a cat"]
    $("#target").each(function() {
      array1.push($(this).html());
    });
    var array2 = ["bat", "cat", "dog"];

    function getMatch(a, b) {
        var matches = [];
        var response = "You got it right"
        for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
            for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {
                //if ( a[i] === b[e] ) matches.push( a[i] );
                if ( a[i] === b[e] ) matches.push(response);
            }
        }
        return Array.from(new Set(matches));
    }   


    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = getMatch(array1, array2);
</script>
```

SO in this js snippet, instead of passing the value to id=#target, it goes to the 'data-answer="[]"'.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Kind regards

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but I have seen something that does not make sense in your code, the use of the each method for an id

Comment: Code adapted from  https://eduardotkoller.github.io/convForm

Comment: A couple things that i notice missing: 1) There are no event listeners so changing the select or typing in the fields does nothing 2) you are setting the innerHTML of a div but the questions says pass an array to an input field.

Comment: I've just self taught myself on js in tbe last 2 weeks. Hardly know much

Comment: @tstrand66 what about the onchange() function?

Comment: @lobjc I must be blind. i am not seeing an onchange() declaration in the snippet above.

Comment: OMG. Let me get to my laptop to edit.

Comment: its $("#target").each(function() not onchange()